# Reusing ExtJs code for Sencha project. Actual experience?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, code-reuse, extjs-mvc

We're currently developing big project using ExtJs 4.0 as a frontend framework. Backend is Entity Framework + SQL Server but it's not important to the matter of this question (I hope).

I'm looking to add mobile version of our application using Sencha Touch. I've read couple articles stating that somewhat 40-50% code can be reused. Does anybody have any **real experience** doing so?

If I'm using ExtJs MVC architecture will I reuse only `models` / `stores` classes? Or is there any way to also reuse for example some of business logic inside `controllers`?

What will be actually project organization and folders structure? Do I need to keep two different trees or is everything can be combined under one roof and only while building different projects I would get different `app-all.js` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some notes here:

Combining Sencha Touch and ExtJS in your Project
http://lanyrd.com/2012/sourcedevcon/srryz/

video no doubt coming soon, senchaworld.com is the place for vids.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could get video from that presentation. Slides are somewhat laconic and not entirely clear...